# Unable to maintain cart in woocommerce using node js

Tags: node.js, woocommerce

I am developing woocommerce application using node js. I am using "wp-json/wc/store/v1/cart/add-item" api to add the products in cart. The issue I am facing is if I am using this api on postman it works completely fine but if I am using this in my node js code then it creates new cart everytime I run this api. It is just not maintaining the same cart. Please help me I am new to woocommerce I am unable to find information regarding this anywhere. I am not sure what is going wrong.

```
async createCart(data, nonce) {
        try {
            let headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                nonce
            }
            const response = await axios.post("https://my-url/wp-json/wc/store/v1/cart/add-item", data, {
                headers
            });
            return response.data;
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return { status: false, error: err.message }
        }
    }
```

above is the code which I am using to add product in cart.

Please guys help me I am really stuck